# How to accumulate scala.util.Try failures?

Tags: scala, validation, scalaz

Suppose I need to accumulate function failures. I can do it easily with `scalaz`:

```
val foo: String => Throwable\/Int = {s => \/.fromTryCatchNonFatal(s.toInt)}
val v1 = foo("abc").validation.toValidationNel
val v2 = foo("xyz").validation.toValidationNel
val v = (v1 |@| v2) {_ + _}
val e = v.toDisjunciton
```

Now I've got a function, which returns `scala.util.Try` instead of `scalaz.\/`

```
val f: String => Try[Int] = {s => Try(s.toInt)}
```

What is best way to accumulate the `scala.util.Try` failures ? Do I need to convert `scala.util.Try` to `scalaz.Validation` and visa versa manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

scalaz 7.2.x contains https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/122e5f9dfc3fbe9189d1f817e703c78047fbb3ef/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/std/Try.scala#L14-L15 which you can use as an idea to create an implicit class which does the conversion to Validation and ValidationNel for you.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this may help you:

```
def accumulate[T](tries:Try[T]*) = tries.collect {case Failure(t) => t}
```